# conflict between php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery, conflict

I have a video  slider "royal slider"  [**from here**](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/) 
it works well alone , but once I integrate the php code with the j query script I got only the first slide and the other video slides are black !

I have tried target the content of the slider and add it to our work

```
   $out_put_data=  file_get_contents('defualt_vedio.php');
```

and I have tried to put the script of the j query inside

```
  $.noConflict();
```

but in-vain , the same result for the slider !

[**Fiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/MustafaAdelElnagar/mLLfx/)

Comment: Can you show us the contents of defualt_vedio.php please?

Comment: thanks alot for your time , this is the content of the defualt_vedio.php

Comment: this is the file http://jsfiddle.net/MustafaAdelElnagar/mLLfx/

Comment: why do u have so much space in `js` file names?? keep in mind `jquery-1          .8          .3          .min          .js` is different from `jquery-1.8.3.min.js` according to server!! :)

Comment: I just made auto replacement to add all this script here , that cause this gaps , sorry for that @NoobEditor  , the file well formatted at jsfiddle , http://jsfiddle.net/MustafaAdelElnagar/mLLfx/

Comment: @MustafaAdelELnagar :  mate..i think u r not getting any answers because mainly your code is not readable ( *badly formatted* ) and also your fiddle is mixed up too...!! :(

Comment: I have re-posted the code at jsfiddle , thanks for your notes !

Comment: @MustafaAdelELnagar : and this time your forgot to post fiddle link in your question....added one from comments, check if its same, if not, update from your side!! :D